# If someone commits a crime in one state and then flees to another state, will he become safe?

Tags: united-states

If one person commits a crime in one american state and then goes fleeing to another state does that mean he is safe?Can one state refuse extradiction to another or must all states help enforce the laws of another state?Will there be any involvement of federal government?What the tthing is that to what extent will things become changed if the crime is not encoded or is exempt in federal law mainly ?


**Content before last edit:**

Let us say there is an offence Z that is punishable with a fine of upto $500000 in state 1 of the United States of America and the accused(who is accused with the crime Z) flees to stateb 2where the act Z is perfectly legal can State 1 successfuly punish the person who does crime Z meaning is intrastate extradiction possible?What if federal laws says nothing about it (Z) is it still punishable?

> 

Let's say there is an offence Z. A person commits that offence in state 1, which gives a $500000 fine for it, and then flees to state 2 which explicitly says Z is not a crime.
Federal law does not a speak on it. Will the criminal still be fined?

Comment: No, if it is not a crime in 'state 2' there would be no legal basis, for 'state 2', to impose the fine.

Answer (score 8):

At half a million I would expect it is qualifies as "felony or other crime" - the U.S. Constitution (Article IV Section 2) requires that:

> A person charged in any State with Treason, Felony, or other Crime,
> who shall flee from Justice, and be found in another State, shall on
> Demand of the executive Authority of the State from which he fled, be
> delivered up, to be removed to the State having Jurisdiction of the
> Crime.

Comment: Assuming that in that state is is a crime (that is what the question is asking: **if it is *not* a crime**). Normally **extradition** is only possible if it is a crime in the state that the person is to be extricated from.

Comment: @MarkJohnson - If you read the excerpt from the Constitution you will see no such criteria.